# Linked List not Propagating through Recursive Calls

Tags: c, bison, yacc

There's a lot of overhead to this question involving yacc, bison, etc, that is building essentially a parsed tree of key elements for calculating strings. But, all of that is working correctly, I'm fairly confident, the issue is with one nagging linked list.

As I mentioned, I'm working with a "calculator" of sorts, but this calculator is supposed to accept variables that have been stored within a linked list. Phrases like (add 1 4) work just fine, but the tricky part is if you try something like ((let (firstvar 2)) (add firstvar 4)) Now, it's supposed to go through a symbol list (a list of 1 in this case) and find the value of firstvar (that was created, instantiated, and assigned with the let statement prior to the add statement) and put it into the chain.

All that to say, the issue is when I try to pass the "symbolList" down to the various operands it overwrites the struct in odd and confusing ways.

First, the main unions from the .h:

```
typedef struct
{
    double value;
} NUMBER_AST_NODE;

typedef struct
{ 
    char *name;
} SYMBOL_AST_NODE;

typedef struct
{
   char *name;
   struct ast_node *op1;
   struct ast_node *op2;
} FUNCTION_AST_NODE;

typedef struct ast_symbol
{
    char *name; //symbol name
    struct ast_node *data;

    struct ast_symbol *next;
    struct ast_symbol *parent;
} AST_SYMBOL;

typedef struct ast_node
{
    AST_NODE_TYPE type;
    union
    {
        NUMBER_AST_NODE number;
        FUNCTION_AST_NODE function;
        SYMBOL_AST_NODE symbol;
    } data;

    AST_SYMBOL *symbolList;    
} AST_NODE;
```

Okay, and now, assuming the tree has been partially created, the issue is that the "symbolList" is attached only to the highest member of the tree... so I need to pass it onto the children (that is, operand 1 & operand 2) so that they will have access to the symbolList and thusly be able to properly translate any variables that are passed into their functions.

So, I'm doing a recursive call like this:

```
void translate(AST_NODE *p)
{
  //recursive infix traversal.
  if(p->type == NUM_TYPE){
      printf("%6f",(double) p->data.number.value);
  }
  else if (p->type == SYM_TYPE){
      resolveSymbol(p->symbolList, p->data.symbol.name); //this goes and finds the variable, and it does it correctly IF it has the symbolList!
  }
  else if(p->type == FUNC_TYPE){
          printf("( ");

          p->data.function.op1->symbolList = p->symbolList; //passing the symbolList onward

          translate(p->data.function.op1);
          printf( " %c ",resolveOp(resolvdfunc)); //ignore this, it's just displaying the char like '+' for add

          p->data.function.op2->symbolList = p->symbolList; //passing the symbolList onward
          translate(p->data.function.op2);
          printf(" )");
    }
  }

   if (!p)
      return;
}
```

Okay, so, FOR EXAMPLE. Let's say that I comment out the second operand's symbolList passing. Then, a statement like ((let (a 2)) (add a 4)) will work just fine. But, obviously, if I try ((let (a 2)) (add 4 a)) it WON'T work because the second operand doesn't have access to the 'a' variable.

The trouble is that, currently, WITHOUT commenting out that second symbolList passing, it OVERWRITES my FIRST operand and it doesn't have access to the symbolList anymore!

I hope this makes sense.... it's been driving me insane.

Thanks.

EDIT: 9:22 -- Here's the resolveSymbol code (as requested)...

```
void resolveSymbol(AST_SYMBOL *p, char *name)
{
    if (p == NULL)
        yyerror("No such symbol exists");
    else if (strcmp(p->name, name) == 0) {
        translate(p->data);
    }
    else
        resolveSymbol(p->next, name);
}
```

Comment: I imagine so on the insanity level. The code in first-passing looks correct, save for that it won't compile. Both `struct ast_node` and `struct ast_symbol` are not in this source list, likewise with `resolveSymbol()`, which is probably important. Somewhere in the cleanup before you posted something key appears lost.

Comment: When you say it overwrites your first operand, what exactly is happening, are the struct values getting corrupted?  Can you please post the code for `resolveSymbol()`?

Comment: It won't compile 'cause I have truncated out a lot so it's easy to read.... but assume the structs are in a header file and they're being passed throughout the program appropriately.

Comment: You have a very odd way of "passing" the symbol list to the recursive call (usually one would just use a extra argument rather than modifying the AST), but there doesn't appear to be any overwriting going on, so if you're seeing odd unexpected changes to your AST, that probably means you have dangling pointers somewhere, which means the code that builds the AST is suspect.

Comment: As a probably unrelated issue to your described problem, you may want to move the `if(!p)` NULL check that's at the end of the `translate` function to the start of it. If `p` happened to be `NULL`, you would have already accessed it anyways on the preceeding `if` blocks.

Comment: @sgorozco ha, true. That was kinda just a hanging thought from forever ago. True that it's unrelated, but also wise to reorder.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not connected to you problem (but might make it easier to solve), it generally makes more sense to pass arguments to recursive functions as arguments rather than hanging them off of unreleated data structures:

```
void translate(AST_NODE *p, AST_SYMBOL *symbols) {
  if(p->type == NUM_TYPE) {
    printf("%6f",(double) p->data.number.value);
  } else if (p->type == SYM_TYPE) {
    resolveSymbol(symbols, p->data.symbol.name);
  } else if(p->type == FUNC_TYPE) {
    printf("( ");
    translate(p->data.function.op1, symbols);
    printf( " %c ", resolveOp(resolvdfunc)); //ignore this, it's just displaying the char like '+' for add
    translate(p->data.function.op2, symbols);
    printf(" )");
  }
}
```

with this you get rid of the symbolList field altogether, and you can traverse the AST data structure without modifying it.

Comment: I would stress modifying the code as @ChrisDodd is suggesting, especially since on the implementation of resolveSymbol, you are calling `translate(p->data)` again, but I don't see any code that would propagate the symbol list to the node structure that `p->data` could be pointing to (unless they can't be of type `FUNC_TYPE`, in which case you may disregard my comment)

Comment: I appreciate this suggestion. It does fix a portion of the error... and your comment on how AST is built may be the issue is additionally worrisome.

What I mean is, this does fix the problem "locally" but it doesn't fix the primary issue, which is that I can't seem to give the symbolList to all of the children without overwriting.... the reason I've asked the question in this manner is because otherwise I'd have to involve 'yacc' and 'bison' which adds unnecessary complexity (I thought) to the issue.

Comment: See, what I want to do is when the AST is built give all the children the symbolList (using this logic)... so how do I find the dangling pointer that's being over written?

Comment: Unless the overwrite is ocurring inside the `resolveOp()` function (I suggest posting that code too), or there is more than one thread manipulating the AST,  it would seem that somehow  `p->data.function.op1`  and  `p->data.function.op2` are pointing to an overlapped area of memory. That could explain the fact that updating `p->data.function->op2->symbolList` is somehow damaging the value of your first operand.  Can you please post the portion of code that is initializing the `function->op1` and `function->op2` pointers?